# How to adapt wilcox.test to my data in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to use wilcox.test on my data : I have a dataframe 36021X246 with rownames as probeIDs and the last row is a label which indicates which group the samples belong to - "control" for the first 140 and "treated" for the last 106.

I would greatly appreciate knowing how to define the two groups when I perform the test....I am unable to find much information on the "formula" argument online except that -

"formula

a formula of the form lhs ~ rhs where lhs is a numeric variable giving the data values and rhs a factor with two levels giving the corresponding groups."

If someone could explain what lhs~rhs means and how to define this formula I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us a snippet of your data? You lose me where you have rows as labels?

Comment: I get annoyed when migration occurs prematurely or inappropriately. There is no code or data here and the questioner clearly is confused about how to apply any sort of Wilcoxon test to his data. The CrossValidated people should not be referring these questions to a coding forum until they have properly educated such questioners. RNewbie: This is the response you _should_ have gotten at CrossValidated:  WHAT is your research question?

Answer (score 1):

R typically assumes that each row is a case and the columns are associated variables. If the cases from both your samples occur in the same data frame, one column would be an indicator variable for sample membership. Let's call is IndSample. The Wilcoxon is a univariate test, so you would have another column containing the response values you are testing on. Let's call it Y.  You then write

```
wilcox.test(y ~ IndSample, data=MyData, .....)
```

and the rest of your parameters for the test: is it two-sided? Do you want an exact statistic? (Probably not, in your case.)

It looks to me as if your data is on its side. That's problematic with a data frame, since you can't just pull out a row from a data frame, the way you would with a matrix.

You need to grab the last row and turn it into a factor - something like

```
factor(c(MyData[lastrow,]))
```

Then pull out the row that contains your response:

```
Y <- as.numeric(c(MyData[ResponseRow,]))
```

Then do the wilcoxon.

However, I am not sure that I have properly understood your situation. That seems to be a very large data matrix for a modest wilcoxon test.